# HTML 5 Form Validation

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to force HTML5 required field validation to execute before the `onsubmit` event handler is called?  Alternatively, is there a way to execute the HTML5 required validation from within the `onsubmit` event handler?

My web form containing several HTML5 `<input>` elements with required attributes. The form's `onsubmit` event handler is assigned using the `onsubmit="PerformWork();"` HTML markup.

The field validation works perfectly without the event handler.  However, when I add the handler the validation stops working and the event handler is called instead.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code?

Comment: element.checkValidity() does the same as beforesubmit on one elm. you can do onchange="this.checkValidity()"

Comment: For some time it has not been considered good practice to use inline event attributes to assign event handlers. *"These attributes should be avoided. This makes the markup bigger and less readable. Concerns of content/structure and behavior are not well-separated, making a bug harder to find. Furthermore, usage of event attributes almost always causes scripts to expose global functions on the Window object, polluting the global namespace."* In my experience submit events added using addEventListener have **not** been fired when the form is invalid.

Comment: @pwdst It's nice to post the source of a quote so we know where you got that from

Comment: I have created a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/kf6KY/ showing that the submit handler is *not* fired when the form is invalid if you attach using addEventListener.

Comment: @AlbertXing I intended to reference the source, but forgot to paste in the Url. Apologies. The source is the Mozilla Developer Network https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes

Comment: @iDev - Which browser are you using? I have forked the original Fiddle to add the event handler using the (not recommended) event attribute and it still did not fire for an invalid form in Internet Explorer 11, Firefox 30 or Chrome 36. http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/99Jex/3/